# Search for emails from either address A or B

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, microsoft-outlook-2016

In Outlook 2016 (Microsoft Exchange):

I want to search for emails that are either from abc@email.com OR xyz@email.com.

Is there a way to use the OR operator when searching for emails in Outlook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to click the search box at the top and enter:

```
from:"abc@email.com" OR from:"xyz@email.com"
```

Notice that there is a space on each side of the OR.

[image]

By the way, if you want to learn more about search in Outlook, refer to: [How to search in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-search-in-outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da).

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Enter the following in the Search box at the top of the Outlook window:

```
from:("abc@email.com") OR from:("xyz@email.com")
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute the search.

The "OR" must be written in upper-case.

Comment: Is there a (web) resource that explains how Outlook search actually works?

Comment: @Hannu: The documentation by Microsoft is very basic. For more complex cases one has to search.

Comment: I bet one must have learnt the MS-lingo to be successful searching that...

Comment: Just a minor note: I don't think the brackets are needed.

Comment: @User1973: I thought so too, but my version of Outlook didn't accept this syntax without the parenthesis.